# Getting error while installing Angular4 npm install -g @angular/cli : - Module not find

Tags: angular4-forms

Getting error while installing Angular4 npm install -g @angular/cli : - Module not find

please find the error screenshots messages .[![enter image description here][1]][1]

find the URL:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpqwa.jpg

Comment: please update any one

Comment: in your package.json which version do you have of zone.js? If it's an old version try to change your package.json to zone.js: 0.8.14 (or 0.8.16).
After you delete a node_modules folder, run again npm install.